# what is this error "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (8869003)"

Tags: google-play-console

i am unable to publish any apps on my Google Play Developer account is says
An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (8869003)
can anyone please help me to get out of this?

Comment: when is this happening? when uploading an apk or publishing?

Answer (score 19):

Had same issue today.
In my case I had to logout and login.
Then everything worked.

Answer (score 2):

In used incognito window and worked. Clearing cookies, cache might also work

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to conflict between chrome signed in account and google console signed in account, signing out from console and resigning in will solve the conflict. Solaza suggested the same solution

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar Android Developer Console Issue today.
I was trying to promote a Closed Testing Track (Beta) to Production.

I always got the following error (with random error codes):
`An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (Random-Error-Code)`

The solution was to create the new release by hand in the Production Track, rather than promoting up the existing Closed Testing Track.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. It could have been because I changed my account email on the same day. I got it working the next day.

Things to try:

- Use a different computer.
- You have to select at least one country from the list of countries to test.
- Give it 24 hours for Google to refresh your email change, and try again.
- If nothing works, contact Google Play Console Customer Support, they have a chat window.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when update my developer profile on google play developer account. There is a featured app selection at the end of the page. I selected an app that is not published yet, caused the problem.

I didn't select that app as featured and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it's due to the network issues that my laptop by default will use our company's system proxy, I guess it'll go through some internal firewalls before reach the outside world, the latency caused the error, i switched to no proxy mode, then everything working fine